# Lengthen server wait time in php

Tags: php, server

So I am not familiar with servers, so please forgive me if I say something stupid.

the problem is that I work with a very old database and it's queries take very long to execute (about 1.5 minutes). when I use this in my website the server can't handel it and give's me a 503 error.

I tried checking how long the server runtime is with this:

```
echo $maxlifetime = ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime");
```

but after a bit of reading I heard this is not the way to do it.

So my question is how do I see the time the server has to load the page before it give's me the 503 error and how do I lengthen it?

thank you for helping.

EDIT

oke this is the query that give's me the error:

```
SELECT FD_DATUM_INGEVOERD || ' ' || FT_TIJD_INGEVOERD FROM BANDZENDINGEN WHERE FB_AFGESLOTEN = 'F' AND FB_AKTIEF = 'T' AND FI_AFVOERKANAAL = 11 AND FI_GEBRUIKER1 = '175' AND FI_VERRIJKINGID < 1
```

it only takes 17 sec to execute in the firebird database.

EDIT 2

it just found out my queries only take a long time if the database is very busy with something.

Comment: What is the real problem here? If an error 503 is thrown, there should be something written to the server's error log. That GC lifetime is not related to long-running queries

Comment: What exactly is your server? There's PHP's timeout, but then there's also the hosting web server's own timeout.

Comment: @deceze it's a sftp server

Comment: Yeah, no, that doesn't help. Do you administer this server, or is it a shared hosting server? If the latter, there's probably nothing you can do. Otherwise, we need to hear something like [tag:apache] or [tag:nginx] or such.

Comment: @NicoHaase the problem is if run queries that take a more than a minute to execute my browser give me the 503 error

Comment: @deceze it's a server from the company where I work for. so yes it is a shared hosting server

Comment: If you work there, you should probably contact your server admins to discuss this with them.

Comment: @deceze I did, they said: "well If you are having trouble with the database you should lengthen the time the server needs to load a page" they where not really helping

Comment: No, it's not the browser giving you an error, it's the server. And it will log the reason for giving up. So, what have you tried to debug the problem? If a query takes long time, have you tried to check for the cause? What about execution plans? Is this after all related to PHP?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried shorting my queries. I will try to lenghten the time the server needs to load the page

Answer (score -1, accepted):

oke just found the answer I will lenghten the execution time of the server with this:

**ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);**

Comment: Even if this solves your current problem, it opens some new ones - what if the execution time for that query gets even longer and multiple requests happen that stack up and lead to high load on your servers. Why not find the real problem and fix that?

Comment: @NicoHaase my company is currently busy  with moving to a new database that is a lot faster and better. so the problem wil just go away, that is why I use this solution

Comment: And what makes you think that "a new database" runs faster if you don't profile and optimize your application?

Comment: because I already do very long and havy queries on that database, even running 50 queries. works perfect

Comment: It's fine to run heavy queries, but if you would share more details about them, there could be room for improvement

Comment: the problem is I can't almost all of my queries have sensitive data in them. (like a name of a user or special codes). I have to be carefull what I share. I was lucky with the query in my question, because taht is one of the few that has no sensitive data.

Comment: And where's the execution plan for this query? I don't want to annoy you, but optimizing queries is something that can really help you as it lowers the load on your servers

Comment: I already have optimized my queries, I put a index on important tables and removed tables form the query. it only takes 17 seconds to execute. for that database that is impressive, because most queries will cost you between 20 and 30 seconds

Comment: I don't know how much data is stored in your tables, but 17 seconds still looks horrible for this simple query

Comment: well there are 100 mil records in the database and the database is a firebird database. so 17 seconds is good for this database